# Error : Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We are having an error in our developed ASP.net application. Error is just below. We deployed this application to many customers. But one of them is getting this error every day. I set the Max Pool Size tp 6000 in connection string but the error keeps occuring. I've analyzed my data access layer to closing connection strategy. But there's no mistake in DAL. When the error is thrown, I executed SP_WHO or SP_WHO2 stored proceducer. There is no open connection and the connection list has an average of 50-60 quantities. I tried every method but I can't resolve the problem.

I'm having this error since the server is changed from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2012.

I suspect the server has been changed or .NET Framework version.

Answer (score 0):

There error is either caused by running out of connections in your pool but if you have set the pool size to 6000 (eeeek) then it won't be that.

The second cause is a connection timeout to the sql box, the default is 15 seconds which should be plenty but you can try increasing it and see if you get less errors - if you do then there is something wrong with sql or the connection between the server and the database.

Please please please make sure you have all our SqlConnections inside using blocks and they are being put back in the pool.

ed